# Create a set of datapoints based off of a value in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet to track a game I play and I'm trying to determine how often I win with a certain character. There is some metadata in the table (like date, location, etc) but the important parts are this:

| Character | Winner |
| --- | --- |
| Yuriko | me |
| Yuriko | Derevi |
| Yuriko | me |
| Yuriko | me |
| Winota | me |
| Winota | Derevi |

I want to be able to have 2 stats columns in my other sheet:

| Yuriko Win % | Winota Win % |
| --- | --- |
| 75% | 50% |

I know how to find the win percentage, but I dont know how to limit my data set by character. Is this possible in Excel?

I'm also happy to use a chart here, if that makes it easier.

Edit: Not the cleanest solution, so if someone has something better, I'm all ears, but heres what I have:

Yuriko Games Played:

```
=COUNTIF('Game Log'!F2:'Game Log'!F500,"Yuriko")
```

Yuriko Wins:

```
=COUNTIFS('Game Log'!K2:K500,"=me",'Game Log'!F2:F500,"=Yuriko")
```

Then I just copy this for Winota too.

Now that I think about it, I'd love maybe a Stacked Chart that could stack the data more visually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Insert formula in `A12` : `=TOROW(UNIQUE(A2:A7,FALSE),0,TRUE)&" Win %"`
It will spill all unique characters in row.
Insert formula in `A13`: `=TOROW(COUNTIFS(A2:A7,UNIQUE(A2:A7),B2:B7,"me")/COUNTIF(A2:A7,UNIQUE(A2:A7)))` it will spill win percentages in rows. Make sure there is enough space to spill data or you will get `#SPILL!` error. For stacked chart just insert stacked chart with win percentages as series values and 12th row as series names.

Comment: This is great and is almost exactly what I want. I have one small issue still though. I dont want to have to keep updating this, so for my range I put A2:A500 and B2:B500. Now one of the Win % rows is "<blank> Win %" and I get a divide by 0 error from the win %. Is there a way to not pick up blanks?

Comment: You need to use FILTER to filter blanks. Try this: =TOROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A500,A2:A500<>""),FALSE),0,TRUE)&" Win %" to get unique characters list and this: =TOROW(COUNTIFS(A2:A500,UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A500,A2:A500<>""),FALSE),B2:B500,"me")/COUNTIF(A2:A500,UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A500,A2:A500<>""),FALSE))) to get percentages. Both formulas ignoring blanks